# How do I name columns that contain restricted characters so that that name is intuitive?

Tags: database, oracle

I have to make a database column that stores the number of people who scored greater than or equal to a threshold of 0.01, 0.1, 1, and 10 at a particular metric I'm tracking.

For example, I want to store the following data

```
Number units quality score >= 0.01  
Number units quality score >= 0.1
Number units quality score >= 1
Number units quality score >= 10
```

So my question is...

How do I name my columns to communicate this?  I can't use the >= symbol or the . charater.  I was thinking something like...

```
gte_score_001
gte_score_01
gte_score_1
gte_score_10
```

Does this seem intuitive?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You *can* use those symbols and characters, but don't... *8-) You could use a `d` to denote the decimal, `gte_score_0d01`, `gte_score_0d1`; though the leading zero implies that anyway.  What is intuitive is a bit subjective though. Maybe come up with a scheme that makes sense to you, and then ask colleagues what they think it means? [You could also add a comment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/COMMENT.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's subjective, but I'd say score_gte_001 would be slightly more intuitive. meets_thresh_001 would be another option that may be slightly clearer than gte.

Then there's the numbers. Avoid the decimal point problem by refering to the numbers either explicitly or implicitly as hundreths:

```
meets_thresh_1c
meets_thresh_10c
meets_thresh_100c
meets_thresh_1000c
```

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are all either integers or less than zero, so there isn't any ambiguity; but that itself might not be obvious to someone else looking at the name, and you could have to add more confusing or even conflicting groups. What would `gte_score_15` mean - it could be read as `>= 15` or `>= 1.5`? And you might need to represent both one day, so your naming should try to be future-proof as well an intuitive.

Including a delimiter to show where the decimal point goes would make it clearer, at least once you know the scheme. To me it makes sense to use the numeric format model character for the decimal separator, `D`:

```
gte_score_0d01
gte_score_0d1
gte_score_1
gte_score_1d5
gte_score_10
gte_score_15
```

though I agree with @L.ScottJohnson that `score_gte_0d01` etc. scans better. Again, it's subjective.

If there is a maximum value for the metric, and a a maximum precision, it *might* be worth including leading zeros and trailing zeros. Say if it can never be more than two digits, and no more than two decimal places:

```
score_gte_00d01
score_gte_00d10
score_gte_01d00
score_gte_01d50
score_gte_10d00
score_gte_15d00
```

The delimiter is kind of redundant as long as you know the pattern - without it, the threshhold is the numeric part/100. But it's maybe clearer with it, and with the padding it's probably even more obvious what the `d` represents.

If you go down this route then I'd suggest you come up with a scheme that makes sense to you, then show it to colleagues and see if they can interpret it without any hints.

---

You could (and arguably *should*) normalise your design instead, into a separate table which has a column for the threshold (which can then be a simple number) and another column for the corresponding number of people for each metric. That makes it easier to add more thresholds later (easier to add extra rows an an extra column) and makes the problem go away. (You could add a view to pivot into this layout, but then you're back to your naming problem.)

Comment: One point of concern: the d notation you've got there is fine except that it conflicts with the same format used for scientific notation in, for example, python (in which 01d50 would mean 1 times 10 to the 50th power).

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to do that? What if it turns out that you need additional threshold of 20. Or 75. Or ...? Why wouldn't you normalize it and use two columns? One that represents a threshold, and another one that represents the number of people.

So, instead of

```
create table some_table
  (<some_columns_here>,
   gte_score_001  number,
   gte_score_01   number,
   gte_score_1    number,
   gte_score_10   number
  );
```

use

```
create table some_table
  (<some_columns_here>,
   threshold           number,
   number_of_people    number
  );

comment on column some_table.number_of_people is 
  'Represents number of people who scored greater than or equal to a threshold';
```

and store values like

```
insert into some_table (threshold, number_of_people) values (0.01, 13);
insert into some_table (threshold, number_of_people) values (0.1,  56);
insert into some_table (threshold, number_of_people) values (1,    7);
```

If you have to implement a new threshold value, no problem - just insert it as

```
insert into some_table (threshold, number_of_people) values (75, 24);
```

Doing *your* way, you'd have to

```
alter table some_table add gte_score_75 number;
```

and - what's even worse - modify *all* other program units that reference that table (stored procedures, views, forms, reports ... the list is quite long).

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes around the column name alias will let you get away with a lot of things.  That removes most limitations on restricted characters and keywords.
I suggest something like this ought to work for display purposes.

```
SELECT 314 "Number units quality score >= 0.01" FROM DUAL
```

Comment: The clarity of  "greater than or equal to less than 0.01" is suspect.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the number of people above a threshold will cause a problem no matter which of these solutions you use. Instead, use a view of the raw data. If you need a new split, you create a new view, you don't have to recalculate any columns. This example is **not** efficient, but is provided as an example:

```
create or replace view thresholds as 
   select 
     (select count(*) c from rawdata where score >= .1) as ".1"
   , (select count(*) c from rawdata where score >= 1 ) as "1"
   , (select count(*) c from rawdata where score >= 10 ) as "10"
   from dual
```